# The context is already tracking the entity - I know but how to solve it?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, entity-framework

I am writing a WPF client application and use WCF Data Service to communicate with a database. I have the following situation: I add a new Policy, it has an attached object House and each House has an Address. In standard Entity Framework application it wasn't a problem but here I need to add relationships between entites. This is my code:

```
context.AddToPolicySet(Policy);
context.AddToAdressSet(Address);
context.AddRelatedObject(Address, "HouseSet", House); 
context.AddRelatedObject(Policy, "HouseSet", House); // !!!!!!!!!!!!
Policy.HouseSet.Add(House);
House.PolicySet = Policy;
Address.HouseSet.Add(House);
House.AdressSet = Address;
```

Now, I understand that the context is already tracking the entity. But how to solve this problem? If I remove the fourth line then I get the error "Insert statement violetes foreign key constraint...". It seems to me that I need to attach a House to the Policy and a House to the Address. But my way is obviously the wrong way. What is the right one? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [AddLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.addlink%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method:

```
context.AddLink(Policy, "HouseSet", House);
```

**EDIT**

It appears to be

```
context.SetLink(House, "PolicySet", Policy);
```

Comment: Gives me the message "Insert statement violetes foreign key constraint...FK_HousePolicy" so I guess it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, maybe it should be AttachLink.

Comment: Now i get: "One or both of the ends of the relationship is in the added state.". I assume that this is because I did context.AddToPolicySet(Policy) before but without it I'll get "Context is not tracking the entity" exception...

Comment: Well, that goes to show I'm not really proficient here. Only tried this stuff once in a while. SetLink?

Comment: SetLink but used in a little different way helped! Thank you :) This is what worked:
context.SetLink(House, "PolicySet", Policy);